# SDL accelerated rendering

Tags: sdl-2

I am trying to understand the whole 2D accelerated rendering process using SDL 2.0.
So my question is which would be the most efficient way to draw circles in the screen and *why*?

Some ways would be:

- First to create a software surface and then draw the necessary pixels on that surface then create a texture out of that surface and lastly copy that texture to the rendering target.
- Also another implementation would be to draw a circle using multiple times SDL_RenderDrawLine.And I think this is the way it is being implemented in SDL 2.0 gfx

Or there is a more efficient way to do all of this?

Take this question more generally in means of if I would wanted to draw other shapes manually, which probably, couldn't be rendered easily with the 2D rendering API that SDL provides(using draw line or rectangle).

Answer (score 1):

With the example of circles this is a fairly complicated question, it is more based on the visual quality you wish to achieve which will drive performance. Drawing lots of short lines will vary vastly based on how close to a circle you wish to get, if you are happy to use say, 60 lines, which will work on small shapes nearly seamlessly but if scaled up will begin to appear not to be a circle, the performance will likely be better (depending on the user's hardware). Note also SDL_RenderDrawLines will be much much faster for many lines as it avoids lots of context switches for rendering calls.

However if you need a very accurate circle with thousands of lines to get a good approximation it will be faster to simply use a bitmap and scale and blit it. This will also give you a 'smoother' feel to the circle.

In my personal opinion I do not think the hardware accelerated render API has much use outside of some special uses such as graph rendering and perhaps very simple GUI drawing. For anything more complex I would usually use bitmap based drawing.

With regards to the second part, it again depends on the accuracy of any arcs you need to draw. If you can easily approximate the shape into a few tens of lines it will be fast, otherwise the pixel method is better.

Comment: When we draw circles in a screen using the line drawing method don’t we actually do it by drawing only horizontal lines?
So for a circle that has 600 pixels in height aren’t 600 line drawings enough no matter how much accurate you want to draw it.(some of them ,actually many, can be drawn as rectangles too).
I think the matter for accuracy comes at the point when you decide where to draw the start of the line and the end (always in horizontal axis).  
Same logic with the Surfaces too.

Comment: @LanPac Ah, I had not realized you had been referring to untextured, filled circles. I had assumed you were referring to hollow ones. However if that is the case, performance wise it will make very little difference either way. The only difference will be the effect, bitmap will allow you to achieve an anti aliased look using smoothing or sub pixel rendering, line drawn will be sharper, performance will vary little.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
Generally bitmaps will be faster.
But my problem is in the case I want to draw the various shapes at runtime.(Without the use of bitmaps)

Comment: @LanPac Ah, I see. In that case the line system will work, though I would bet per pixel and per line construction will be fairly similar in speed anyway. Thanks